# Modify build in terminal command

Tags: android, android-ndk, adb

I want to modify this build in terminal command of android

[screenrecord](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/idea133/cmds/screenrecord/screenrecord.cpp)

Is there a way to replace the command once I compiled it or do I have to compile a full custom android version

If it is possible to replace it how would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the correct site to all this question. However if you're on Ubuntu, take a look at http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi

Answer (score 0):

`screenrecord` uses non-public APIs, so you can't build it with the NDK.  You need to have a full build tree to get the necessary headers and libraries.  Once built, though, you should be able to run it on a device with the same version of Android (i.e. if you have a 4.4 tree, it should work on any 4.4 device), but that's not guaranteed.

Note that `screenrecord` has been [updated](http://bigflake.com/screenrecord/) from the version you linked; the Android 5.0 version is [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/lollipop-release/cmds/screenrecord/).

Comment: How would I swap my version with the old version. By installing a custom rom on my device it is there a mor lightweight method

Comment: I don't think anything relies on the location of screenrecord, so you could just install a new binary in (say) /data/local/tmp and execute it from there.  It just has to be on a volume mounted with exec enabled, so it can't live on /sdcard.